# Strange implementation of Object.Equals

Tags: c#

I was reading the [MSDN documentation about `object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx). in the remarks part it mentioned:

> If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and
>   neither is null, it calls **objA.Equals(objB)** and returns the result.
>   This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method,
>   this override is called.

My question is why they did not implement this part as `objA.Equals(objB) && objB.Equals(objA)` to make equality symmetric and just relate on one side of the relation? It can result in strange behaviors when calling `object.Equals`.

**EDIT:** Strange behavior can happen when type of objA overrides `Equals` method and implemented it as something not predictable, but type of objB does not override `Equals`.

Comment: If A equals B, then we already know B equals A, and if A does not equal B, then B cannot equal A. Why would you expect another comparison?

Comment: Any time it would make a difference, the implementation of `Equals` is broken, basically. It's documented that it *must* be reflexive.

Comment: @TiesonT. if B has overridden Object.Equals than it can give different result

Comment: If objA and objB has different types and objA overrides `Equals` method but not objB, the problem arises.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think the .net guys could solve the problem simply by checking `objA.Equals(objB) && objB.Equals(objA)`. Why they put something unpredictable in .net?

Comment: @alisabzevari: Well it would make it take twice as long (in the equality case) for everyone, despite only affecting bad implementations. Are you going to suggest that a hash table should also check every entry for equality and ignore the hash code, just because some people don't know how to implement that, too? Basically, if you don't follow the rules of the method you're overriding, you're going to introduce problems. That will always be the case - there's no reason to penalize other people for it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't mean penalizing people. I am just learning here, From you, people who implemented .net and other experienced programmers in SO. I always thinking that a good library must narrow the ways of using it to minimize need of reading documentation. I seems that there is too much to learn here about this problem. I was thinking about it very simple and naively!

Comment: Any developer who isn't willing to read the documentation of a method they're *overriding* to find out what it needs to do has big, big problems IMO. Will convert my comment into an answer.

Comment: i think this "Strange implementation of Object.Equals" is more flexible and better. you can change it by your self to make it inflexible with that simple condition

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Basically, this would only be of any use to developers with flawed `Equals` implementations. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47):

> The following statements must be true for all implementations of the `Equals(Object)` method. In the list, `x`, `y`, and `z` represent object references that are not null.
>
> - [...]
> - `x.Equals(y)` returns the same value as `y.Equals(x)`.
> - [...]

So the check is redundant in every case where the method has been correctly implemented - causing a performance hit to every developer who has done the right thing.

It isn't even terribly useful to developers who *haven't* done the right thing, as they may still expect `object.Equals(x, y)` to return `true` when it returns `false` - they could debug and find that *their* method returns true, after all. You could say that it would be documented to check both ways round - but we've already established that the only developers this affects are ones who don't read the documentation anyway.

Basically, when you override a method or implement an interface, you should know what you're doing and obey the specified contract. If you don't do that, you *will* get odd behaviour, and I don't think it's reasonable to expect every caller to try to work around implementations which don't do what they're meant to.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that a good practice in a `Equals` implementation is to check if both objects share the same type: `obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(otherObj.GetType())`. That being true, there is no worry that whatever comes after will be symmetric valid.

Comment: @PauloAvelar: I would use `obj.GetType() == otherObj.GetType()` usually; allowing instance of two different types in the same hierarchy to be equal can cause issues.

Comment: Good to know. I'm more versed in Java, so my instinct was to use `instanceof`. :)

Comment: @PauloAvelar: In Java I'd use `obj.getClass() == otherObj.getClass()` to check that the types are exactly the same, usually.